# My windows service cant stop, after i implemented Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

My service is installed by wix and starts all fine and did work like i wanted until i added a Thread to my service, so probably i dont shut down the Thread correctly

Here is the Service

```
public class WCFWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

    public WCFWindowsService()
    {
        // Name the Windows Service
        ServiceName = "ServiceName";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new WCFWindowsService()); 
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadTheClass T = new ThreadTheClass();

            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
            Thread _thread = new Thread(T.ThreadMain);
            _thread = new Thread(T.ThreadMain);
            _thread.Start();

            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProjectWCF.WCFService));
            serviceHost.Open(); 
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ThreadTheClass T = new ThreadTheClass();

            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                WCFWindowsService ThreadPost = new WCFWindowsService();

                T.ThreadStop();


                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
    }
}
```

And the Thread Class

```
class ThreadTheClass
{
    System.Threading.Timer MyTimer;
    public void ThreadMain()
    {
        int Minutes = 2;
        MyTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((s) =>
        {
            Logic();
        }
        , null, 5000, Minutes * 100 * 60);

    }

    public void ThreadStop()
    {
        MyTimer.Dispose();
    }

    void Logic()
    {
        //do things every two minutes 
    }
```

I dont know what is wrong cause when i try this in console program, The `ThreadStop()` works fine and shuts down the thread so why cant it shut down in windows service?

i get this error when i try to stop the installed service
[image]

Comment: There are *many* errors with your threading logic. I don't know where to start.

Comment: If everything was working fine, why did you try to add other threads?

Comment: I needed a new Thread to make POST:s to a webbpage every 5 minutes while the other thread is ready for WCF - Soap calls. that way the client knows the external IP from my where my program is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious error is here, in `OnStop`:

```
ThreadTheClass T = new ThreadTheClass();
```

That's creating a *new* instance of `ThreadTheClass`. One for which `MyTimer` will be `null`.

Instead, in your `OnStart` method, you need to store the instance that you're creating there, so that `OnStop` can access that same instance.

```
ThreadTheClass T;

 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        T = new ThreadTheClass();

            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
            T.ThreadMain();

            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProjectWCF.WCFService));
            serviceHost.Open(); 
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                WCFWindowsService ThreadPost = new WCFWindowsService();

                T.ThreadStop();


                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
    }
```

I've also removed the code that created (2!) new `Thread`s - since `ThreadMain` just establishes a timer and then exits, there's no reason to put that on its own thread.

Comment: Thank you i will test this! and i see your points with the 2 Threads and that. this helped alot